# Convergence in sequence spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n^{(k)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\to(y_n)$ for $k\to\infty$ in $l_\infty$, that is $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \vert x_n^{(k)}-y_n\vert\to 0$ for $k\to\infty$. Now, when can we say that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\vert x_n^{(k)}-y_n\vert^2\to 0,\quad (k\to\infty)?$$ What is needed from $(x_n^{(k)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_n)$? That they a-priori be convergent to zero? What about the other way around?

I know $l_2$ and $l_\infty$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: All $x_n^{(k)}$ are real numbers? What means $(x_n^{(k)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\to(y_n)$ for $k\to\infty$? For each $n$, $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_n^{(k)} =y_n$?

Comment: The condition $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\vert x_n^{(k)}-y_n\vert^2\to 0$ is much more strict than $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \vert x_n^{(k)}-y_n\vert\to 0$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky. Yes $x_n^{(k)}$ are real numbers. No, I meant convergence in $l_2$ resp. $l_\infty$. Should I have rather written $((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}^{(k)})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\to (y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ for $k\to\infty$?